# Seeing the http request in wicket

Tags: java, web, wicket

I'm using Apache Wicket and I want to see the http request itself (Exact text of the request without any processing!). What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For Wicket 1.5 you can get the underlying request object and cast it to HttpServletRequest:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest().getContainerRequest());
```

Comment: It does not have such method. In addition it does not know HttpServletRequest. I'm using wicket 1.4.20

Comment: Yes - this works for Wicket 1.5. The HttpServletRequest is part of the servlet specc. You should add an appropriate jar to your project.

Answer (score 3):

In Wicket 1.4, you can get the `HttpServletRequest` object (which is the servlet representation of the request, the rawest you can get) with this code:

```
HttpServletRequest req = ((WebRequest)RequestCycle.get().getRequest()).getHttpServletRequest();
```

However, the "without any processing" part will not work for two reasons: the servlet engine itself will do some processing (like decoding url parameters) and Wicket will have consumed the input stream containing the request entity.

If you want to monitor the raw requests, you have to intercept it on the webserver level.

Comment: How should I do it on the webserver level?

Comment: Depends on the webserver really. Alternatively you can use Wireshark to capture all network traffic to and from the port. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

```
final Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
```