# Extract URL from HttpServletRequest

Tags: java

I am maintaining a Java servlet application and now have to extract the URL from the web service request to determine what action to take depending on what URL called the web service.  I have found that it is something to do with HttpServletRequest which I have imported to the class.  I have tried setting up the following inside the web service end point but it keeps telling me that the urlrequest is not initialised.  What am I doing wrong?

```
HttpServletRequest urlrequest;
StringBuffer url = urlrequest.getRequestURL();
```

Comment: Your HttpServletRequest  is not even initialized here. Usually you would have something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983293/seeing-the-http-request-in-wicket   

If your question would share more information about it's context, this would be very helpful...

Comment: @chrispolzer.  Understood Chris.  I didn't build the servlet and the code is quite extensive.  I can tell you there are six web service requests or end points.  The first is a login with parameters of uername and password and returns a session id for the http session. The other web service requests have the parameters of session id and unique ID for the subject the request is on.  As I said I need to interrogate the HttpServletRequest to obtain the URL which determines what action to take.

Comment: Yes, i think the answers are coming in below?

Answer (score 3):

The HttpServletRequest you are using should be the input parameter HttpServletRequest of either doGet,doPut,doPost or doDelete.
Then Surely `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL` will reconstruct the URL used by the client,excluding the query string parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but it has to be accessed within the `doPost(request, response)`, `doGet(request, response)` etc. methods of a class extending HttpServlet.

The reason for this is the when the `service()` method of HttpServlet is called, it populates the request and response objects for you given the client who prompted the request to your servlet.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a variable in java and call a method on it without initializing it beforehand.
In the first line: `HttpServletRequest urlrequest;` you are just defining a variable. Since it is not initialized it is `null` and you cannot use it.

Remove this line and use the argument passed to the `doGet` (or `doPost`) method in your Servlet.
For example if your servlet is like this:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    ...

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ...
}
```

Instead of your code just add below line in the body of the doGet method:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ...
    StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
    ...
}
```

After this line you should be able to use the `url` variable.

Comment: LOL! Well spotted! I haven't even considered the var delaration a part of his code! :))

Comment: LoL I see. 95% of software bugs are super simple mistakes like this.

Comment: @AliMotevallian - Apologise for the late response but another system had a large problem. Thanks for this and I can see where you are coming from but how do I create the parameter "request" from inside the web service that will call the doGet procedure

Comment: Look you need to provide more code so that I can help better. Your questions are a bit wage and that is why you do not get exact answers. At least show us the doGet method in your servlet. Filling in the request parameter passed to doGet is something the servlet engine will take care of it. You just consume it in your code. You do not need to initialise it or set its attributes.